# How to know if it is select / textbox / radio / checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
parent.find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        console.log($(this));           
});
```

I want to know if `$(this)` is `text / checkbox / radio / select / textarea`

How can I achieve that?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check `this.tagName`. If it's `INPUT`, check the `type` attribute.

Comment: Like this `$('.parent input[type=checkbox], .parent input[type=select]')`

Comment: try `.prop('tagName')`

    parent.find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));           
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `is`?

```
parent.find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        if($(this).is('input')){
          console.log('Input it is');           
        } 
        ...            
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/